# How to render template after ajax Post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

i am trying to post a form using ajax and then render a template it using but it returns the first HttpResponse.

Here is the Post method

```
def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        context = {}
        self.object = self.get_object()
        user_checkout_id = request.session.get('user_checkout_id')
        user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_checkout_id)
        nonce = request.POST.get("payment_method_nonce")


        if request.POST.get('action') == 'guest':
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            user_checkout , created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=email)

            if created:
                self.request.session['user_checkout_id'] = user_checkout.id
                user_checkout.save()

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status' : 'True'}))


        if request.POST.get('action') == 'order':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
            mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
            alternate = request.POST.get('alternate')

            address , created = UserAddress.objects.create(user = user_checkout , name=name , address=address , pincode=pincode ,  mobile_number=mobile , alternate_number=alternate)


            if created:
                self.request.session["address_id"] = address.id

            html = render_to_string('orders/new_order.html', {'order': self.get_order()})

            return HttpResponse(html)


        if nonce:
            result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
                "amount" : order_total ,
                "payment_method_nonce" : nonce ,
                "options":{
                "submit_for_settlement": True
                }

                })
            if result.is_success:
                order.mark_completed(order_id = result.transaction.id) 

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders'))  

        else:
            HttpResponseBadRequest("error")
```

Here is the script that which posts data using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getOrder() {
        $("#loading-image").show();
        name = $("#name").val();
        address = $("#addrs").val();
        pincode = $("#pincode").val();
        mobile = $("#mobile").val();
        alternate = $("#alternate").val();
        console.log(name + address + pincode + mobile + alternate);
        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            data : { action : 'order' , csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' , name:name , address:address , pincode:pincode , mobile:mobile , alternate:alternate },
            url: "{% url 'checkout' %}",
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
                alert(error);  
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

what can be the problem...help needed

**edits**
else included with HttpBadRequest

Comment: What happens if none of those `if` statements are true?

Comment: So i need to give else statements for every if statement?

Comment: Not necessarily, a catch-all at the end that returns an error might be fine, it depends on what you want the behaviour to be.

Comment: How can i write that catch all .Thank you

Comment: i want to execute the if statements according to the action value that is coming with the ajax request

Comment: just return an http response at the bottom of the method... that will be a catch all, eg `return HttpResponseBadRequest("this isn't supposed to happen, I have a bug")`

Comment: the fact that `None` is returned is telling you that none of your `if` statements were matched (python functions return `None` if you don't explicitly return a value)

Comment: i tried else statement at the end of all the ifs and then tried posting but it returns the first HttpResponse.

Comment: if it's returning an http response then that invalidates the premise of your question

Comment: Thanks  @Anentropic it returns after i include an else statement but it is returning the first one...but i have an action coming along the ajax request..it must match with the if statement ie the second if statement with the action and return that Httpresponse where i want the template to be rendered..

Comment: It returns status : True.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100976/discussion-between-adrafe-rinzzler-and-anentropic).

Comment: Can you add a "print request.POST" at the beginning of the view, so we can see what really comes up?